# Jooq - How to get entity class name to extend generic class with DefaultGeneratorStrategy override

Tags: kotlin, jooq, jooq-codegen

I'm using the Jooq generator, and for each DAO I want to have a simple generic interface that each DAO extends for basic crud functions.

Something like `CrudDao<ItrNeGroup>` where `ItrNeGroup` is the POJO name for the table (it extends `NamedEntity`)

How do I determine the class name for the POJO based on the Definition passed to the `getJavaClassImplements` method, and how do I create a type reference that will be understood?

My current method is (second if statement is the relevant one):

```kotlin
override fun getJavaClassImplements(definition: Definition, mode: GeneratorStrategy.Mode): List<String> {
        LOGGER.info("Class Implements: Generator mode is $mode for ${definition.qualifiedName}")
        if (mode == GeneratorStrategy.Mode.POJO && definition.name?.startsWith("itr_ne_") == true) {
            return listOf(NamedEntity::class.java.name)
        }
        if(mode == GeneratorStrategy.Mode.POJO && definition.name?.startsWith("itr_ne_") == true) {
            val tr = object: TypeReference<CrudDao<WHAT_IS_THE_POJO_CLASS>>
            return listOf(tr)
        }
        return emptyList()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return `"CrudDao<" + getJavaClassName(definition, Mode.POJO) + ">"` to get the strategy's POJO class name for the table. You can assume it's already imported because it's referenced from elsewhere. Otherwise, just call `getFullJavaClassName(definition, Mode.POJO)`

Comment: Thanks Lukas - any ideas on the second part of the question (how to return a type reference to a generic? For Jackson I'd do `val tr = object: TypeReference<CrudDao<WHAT_IS_THE_POJO_CLASS>>`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just return a `List<String>` (where `String` is the string version of your type)

Comment: I want to do that because: I have lots of entities that have id, name and I want to have a CRUDService<EntityX>, CRUDService<EntityY> and so on, where EntityX and EntityY are the POJOS. To do this, I need to be able to have the generated dao implement `CRUDService<T> where T -> EntityX`

Comment: I don't understand why you need a `TypeReference`, when you can just generate `"CrudDao<" + getJavaClassName(definition, Mode.POJO) + ">"`

Comment: Well, that's the answer then - I don't need a type reference. Thanks!